# Is there a word / adjective to describe someone who’s set themselves entirely to cause problems to a person?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

For example if a woman is so jealous of another woman and dedicates her life to cause problem after problem to ruin this woman’s life.

Answer (score 4):

A common word for such a person is *[bane](https://unabridged.merriam-webster.com/unabridged/bane)*, as in

> Louisa made herself the *bane* of Jane's existence

From Merriam-Webster Unabridged:

> **bane**, *n.*, **2b**: a person who makes another completely miserable

Comment: Thank you very much I believe this is the word I was looking for

Comment: @Inaya if this is the answer that meets your needs, please accept it by checking the checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to accept a noun rather than an adjective, I suggest *nemesis*.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nemesis) defines *nemesis* as "one that inflicts retribution or vengeance" or "a formidable and usually victorious rival or opponent".

> In English, *nemesis* originally referred to someone who brought a just retribution, but nowadays people are more likely to see animosity than justice in the actions of a nemesis.

*Nemesis* is similar to *enemy*, but implies more about the person's motivations. You can have an enemy who does not hate you personally. But your nemesis truly despises you.

Comment: Thank you for expanding my knowledge ai learnt a new word and your suggestion was very helpful!

Comment: @Inaya if a suggestion is helpful (even if it's not the answer you ultimately choose), the best thanks is an upvote. You can vote up by clicking the up arrow next to this answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Archenemy** (also archfoe) ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/archenemy))

> A principal enemy.
>
> A supreme and most powerful enemy.

**Scourge** ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/scourge))

> A source of persistent trouble such as pestilence that causes pain and
> suffering or widespread destruction.
>
> A means to inflict such pain or destruction.

She is my archfoe. The speaker may be a passive or counterattacking party.

She is my scourge. The speaker presumably is only professing to be the victim party.

Answer (score 0):

[Stalker/ Stalking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stalking)

> Stalking is unwanted and/or repeated surveillance by an individual or group toward another person.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stalking) Stalking behaviors are interrelated to harassment and intimidation and may include following the victim in person or monitoring them.

> Stalking can consist of an accumulation of a series of actions which, by themselves, can be legal, such as calling on the phone, sending gifts, or sending emails.[17]

> Stalkers may use overt and covert intimidation, threats and violence to frighten their victims. They may engage in vandalism and property damage or make physical attacks that are meant to frighten. Less common are sexual assaults.[15]

> Disruptions in daily life necessary to escape the stalker, including changes in employment, residence and phone numbers, take a toll on the victim's well-being and may lead to a sense of isolation.[19]

> Stalking is a form of mental assault, in which the perpetrator repeatedly, unwantedly, and disruptively breaks into the life-world of the victim, with whom they have no relationship (or no longer have). Moreover, the separated acts that make up the intrusion cannot by themselves cause the mental abuse, but do taken together (cumulative effect).

Answer (score -1):

**Sinister** would seem to fit the bill.

Per *Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English*

*Sinister* (adjective)

> making you feel that something evil, dangerous, or illegal is happening or will happen

*Her dark eyes and evil laugh made her seem sinister.*

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary

Other good choices: *malicious*, *spiteful*, *mean*.